# Структура access log

Tags: сервер, запрос, access, логирование

Мне необходимо распарсить access log в dataFrame, но перед этим я бы хотела разобраться в его структуре.
Как я поняла, первым идет IP-адрес пользователя, затем дата его запроса к серверу, после этого уже сам запрос, затем код ответа сервера и наконец, размер ответа сервера в байтах. 
Вот понятно, первым идет IP-адрес:

> 99.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245

А здесь нет формата адреса, имеется ссылка. Как ее интерпретировать?

> tornado.umd.edu - - [20/Jul/2005:19:32:05 -0400] "GET
>   /shuttle/missions/sts74/sts-74-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 5494

И еще один вопрос: после даты запроса пользователя во всех записях стоит -0400. Что это?

Comment: На всякий случай замечу, что структуру можно изменить в настройках и поэтому она может отличаться на разных серверах

Comment: А то, что у вас во втором случае ссылка, это как-то ненормально, лично я такого не встречал ни на одном сервере. Не расскажете, где и как вы такое получили?

Comment: а -0400 это ваша временная зона UTC -4 часа

Comment: Вопрос номер раз: какой у вас веб-сервер?

Answer (score 0):

я нашла, оказывается, там было все написано

1) host making the request. A hostname when possible, otherwise the Internet address if the name could not be looked up.

2) timestamp in the format "DAY MON DD HH:MM:SS YYYY", where DAY is the day of the week, MON is the name of the month, DD is the day of the month, HH:MM:SS is the time of day using a 24-hour clock, and YYYY is the year. The timezone is -0400.

3) request given in quotes.

4) HTTP reply code.

5) bytes in the reply.